Why is my Powerline adapter connection under 100 Mbps?
I have a fiber line with a  speed of 1 Gbps. When I plug a PC directly into the router I get around 900-950 Mbps.
I'm trying to get the internet to other rooms in my house using Powerlines adapters. I've tried 2 PowerLines: 2 x Netgear 500Mbps and 2 x Devolo 1200Mbps.
In both cases (with Netgear or with Devolo) the internet speed that I get on my PC in other rooms is under 100 mbps (85-90Mbps).
The distance between powerline adapters is low 5-6 m.
Why? What can I do?

Powerline adapters notoriously lose significant speed due to a variety of factors, many due to the quality of electrical wiring and connectors between the devices. The fact you've getting the same speeds with different devices indicates this is a wiring issue, and it may not be limited to the wires specifically between the outlets these two devices are connected to.

The answer on this question deals with a lot of the specific aspects that can impact your powerline connection: https://superuser.com/questions/486196/thinking-of-powerline-adapters-for-networking And suggests the best solution: you should seriously consider using wireless instead.

Are all of the adapters on the same circuit (same breaker, etc), and all connected to the same ground? (From what I remember, being able to use all 3 wires is a lot like MIMO in Wi-Fi.)

@grawity All adapters are on the same circuit. , all connected to the same ground. In that electrical line are connected only the Pc , and Power line adapters. The electrical line is composed by 3 wires x 2.5.
